# Words including given string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm writing little Rails api application, and I need to analyze string to find words having given string like:

Assuming my source text is `hello mr one two three four nine nineteen` and I want to check occurence of `on`, it will produce: `one`, and if I'll check occurence of `ne t` in the same string it will result in `one two`.

I know there is an ugly way with substrings, counting positions and parsing string this way, but I think it can be solved with regex scan.

Please say if you need some additional information, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
▶ str = 'hello mr one two three four nine nineteen'
#⇒ "hello mr one two three four nine nineteen"
▶ re = ->(pattern) { /\p{L}*#{pattern}\p{L}*/ }
▶ str[re.('ne t')]
#⇒ "one two"
▶ str[re.('on')]
#⇒ "one"
```

[Matcher `\p{L}`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) is generally better than `\w` and, especially, `\S` because it matches *all utf-8 letters*.

To match accented letters as well (i. e. combined `ï` in “naïve”,) one should extend left and right matchers:

```
▶ re = ->(pattern) { /[\p{L}\p{Mc}]*#{pattern}[\p{L}\p{Mc}]*/ }
```

Please note, that code above will return *the first match*. To return all matches, use `String#scan` instead of `String#[]`:

```
▶ str.scan re.('ni')
#⇒ ["nine", "nineteen"]
```

Comment: ...or put in a method: `def match(str, pattern); str[/[\p{L}\p{Mc}]*#{pattern}[\p{L}\p{Mc}]*/]; end`. (я тоже)

Comment: Thanks, Cary, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
search = "on"
/\s([^\s]*#{search}.[^\s]*)\s/.match("hello mr one two three four nine nineteen")[1]
#  returns "one"

search = "ne t"
/\s([^\s]*#{search}.[^\s]*)\s/.match("hello mr one two three four nine nineteen")[1]
#  returns "one two"
```

The way it works is it finds the substring you are looking for, and then groups any additional characters that are attached to the ends of your substring stopping at the first whitespace on both ends.

Comment: `[^\s]` is to be written as `\S`, and your solution will match punctuation, as commas, dots etc. Besides that, it won’t match words in the beginning of string (“hello” in the example given) and words ending the string (“nineteen”.) That said, this solution is neither robust nor even correct.